# How to unassociate my askubuntu account with my email and delete it?

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts

Askubuntu has been amazing with providing me with useful information and I recommended it highly to others I know using Ubuntu. I now have no purpose for this account because I converted my computer back to Windows. If anyone could tell me how to unassociate my askubuntu account with my email as well as delete it, that would be great.

Answer (score 6):

We, as moderators, can delete your account. However, I'd recommend keeping it around. There's no real harm in it being here and if you ever do switch back to Ubuntu you'll have your previous rep already.

If you do still wish to continue with the deletion, bet aware that this is a permanent deletion and there will be no way to re-associate your account with your previous questions/answers. If that's okay just drop a comment on this answer saying so and I'll have it removed.

Comment: So there is no greater security risk by having another site that I will not use often linked to my email?

Comment: @George If you consider a website having your email address a security risk, then you *could* say this is harmful. However, this site doesn't store any passwords or other sensitive information. So it's your call :)